# how to pass jquery scope on click on a element?

Tags: jquery, function, button, scope, click

i have this example"

```
<div class="tmpl">
    <a href="javascript:button()" class="qwe">Button</a>
</div>

function button(){
    $(this).attr('class');
}
```

it looks like i have no access to the `attr` or anything else, `$(this)` or `this` doesnt seem to be in jQuery scope.

Any ideas how to make this work withowt using a `on("click", function...)` method ?

edit: the html snippet was added dynamically, so there might be a `live` issue ??

Comment: I believe you have to use `<a href="#" onclick="button.call(this)" class="qwe">Button</a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use

```
<div class="tmpl">
    <a href="#" onclick="button(event)" class="qwe">Button</a>
</div>

function button(event){
    event = event || window.event;
    alert($(event.target).attr('class'));
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ucJRA/1/)

Comment: so `$(this)` becomes `$(event.target)`

Comment: yes, you can get the target of the click event using `event.target`

Answer (score 1):

Pass in the param:

```
 <div class="tmpl"> 
   <a href='#' onclick="button(this)" class="qwe">Button</a>
   <a href='#' onclick="button(this)" class="qqq">Button2</a>
   <a href='#' onclick="button(this)" class="666">Button3</a>
</div>       //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----use onclick event instead
```

then:

```
function button(elem) {
   alert($(elem).attr('class'));
}
```

#### [CHECKOUT THE UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dUufv/1/)

Comment: `Object [object global] has no method 'attr' `

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `this` inside `button` refers to `window`, not to the clicked element.

The script in the `href` attribute is executed in global scope just like a normal function. You won't be able to access the clicked element from there.

If you want to bind the event handler via attributes (for whatever reason) and access the element, you have to use proper inline event handlers:

```
<a href="#" onclick="button.call(this)" class="qwe">Button</a>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p4brV/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p4brV/ ... the function `button` must be defined in global scope. But if you have an element with ID `button`, there might be a name collision. In that case, give your function a different name (or the element).

Answer (score 0):

the qwe is not a attribute but a class name, try `$(elem).attr('class')`

**update**
as noted by others you need to change the onclick aswell:
`<a href="javascript:button(this)" class="qwe">Button</a>`